# Dynamically create new component without using an array or setstate

Tags: reactjs, websocket, notifications

This may be incredibly simple but for the life of me I can't figure out how to achieve it.

I have a notification system working through websockets and every time a new notification gets sent, I add it to an array in state and re map to include the notification. each notification has its own timeout so I'm able to remove them programatically... but.... each notification also has an animated logo which basically resets every time a new notification appears. This happens due to the array being mapped each time and therefore the animation begins again as it's essentially a new notification... so I end up with several notifications all having their animation in sync.

Ultimately i'd like to be able to receive a new notification, render it and not touch set state... is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it depends on how exactly you are doing animations. Is it purely CSS animation or JS-driven one? Usually such behavior would mean that components are being remounted on every update. This can be changed by providing consistent `key` attribute, such as a unique `id` that identifies a notification.

Comment: thank you for the help with this. I had already added a key to each of the mapped items but after testing, it was a js animation that was restarting each time. It doesn't look like there's any way to prevent it from restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure your existing notifications have the same keys as before, they shouldn't rerender when you add a new notification to your array in state.

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-shape-6vqmc) in which you can generate new notifications without triggering re render for existing notifications.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I had already added a key to each mapped component but after testing with the example you sent. the animation continues but the js animation I have embedded into the div does restart. Not sure there's any way to stop this from happening.

Comment: Are you sure that the keys for each notification don't change when a new notification is added?

Comment: I'm using the objects id which stays the same and adding the same number format to it. The objects now fade out animation (css) but the lottie/aftereffects animation restarts each time. I might see if I can pass a key further into the package